# rails Add email address to cc without actual sending it to this address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, actionmailer

I have small rails script that can receive emails of our internal employees emails and recent it to real address.

My work flow look likes this:

Admin sent email to Customer real address and Employee internal address, then system parse email change customer real address to system internal, and sent this email to employee real address, which he use, but at this moment I can't cc customer internal address, because it will sent this email to customer again.

So my question is, how I can add email address to cc so that user can see both recipient, but without actual sending that email to customer. Is it even possible?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You can't address this at the Rails level, you need to basically break your mail server to make this work. Why not just include the second address in the body of the email, and then strip it out before resending it?

Comment: Why not just set up forwarding addresses?

Comment: @meagar yes, this is current solution, but this require when you response to the letter additional work: copy customer email address and add to To: field, and I just want to make this easy for users

Comment: @DaveNewton I have to change customer email address from external to internal, and only after this sent it to employee

Comment: @iggbs Then something is wrong with how you're fowarding; your mail server should be able to forward, preserving the original sender's address.